how to check only some options in a form with hook form alter
i am using hook form alter on drupal 9 and I want some of the select options to be checked . I can change the select options, but i can't make only some of them be checked
i tried setting the default value like this $form['field_learning_path_category_target_id']['#default_value'] = array(11); where 11 is the key of the options which i want selected. 
which has no effect , as well as changing the attributes as below but only succeed in getting all of them checked with the code below , how do i check only the ones i want ?
 $form['field_learning_path_category_target_id']['#attributes'] =  [
            'id' => 11,
            'checked' => true,
       ];

and
$form['field_learning_path_category_target_id']['#attributes'] =  array('checked' => 'checked');


i tried setting the default value which has no effect you must of done something wrong.

$form['field_learning_path_category_target_id']['#default_value'] = array(11);  where 11 is the key of the options which i want selected.  that gives no effect

Is this a node edit form?

its a views exposed form

I installed this module https://www.drupal.org/project/form_options_attributes
and then added this line
$form['field_learning_path_category_target_id']['#options_attributes'] = array(11 => array('checked' => 'checked'));

and it works
